# Create a new factorial variable with levels based on intervals of a numeric variable of another dataset

Tags: r, variables, conditional-statements

I have a dataset with a large numeric variable. I want to create a new character variable, that assigns a categorical value to each observation based on a numeric interval.

For instance, if the numeric variable is between 0 and 5, the category will be "B1", if it is between 5 and 10, it will be "B2".

There is a nice answer that solves this
[Coding a new factor based on levels of a numeric variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241359/coding-a-new-factor-based-on-levels-of-a-numeric-variable/56242028#56242028)

But I already have a table with the factor levels and the numeric intervals of each one. Is there a way to do the same but applying the table directly instead of writing the conditions?

Comment: Could you please share more information about the table you have such as the structure? For example, can you edit your question and include a sample of the table data (using `dput`)?

Comment: Sounds as if you are looking for `cut`, e.g. something like `x <- 0:10; cut(x, breaks = c(0, 5, 10), labels = c("B1", "B2"), right = FALSE)`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data shared via `dput`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your interval table is organized, you may also be able to join it to your main dataset. Here's a more or less generic example based on `cars` dataset, we'll use `dplyr::left_join()` with overlap, `join_by(between(cyl, lower, upper, bounds = "[)"))` :

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
(mtcars_ <- mtcars[10:20, "cyl", drop = FALSE] |> as_tibble(rownames = "car"))
#> # A tibble: 11 × 2
#>    car                   cyl
#>    <chr>               <dbl>
#>  1 Merc 280                6
#>  2 Merc 280C               6
#>  3 Merc 450SE              8
#>  4 Merc 450SL              8
#>  5 Merc 450SLC             8
#>  6 Cadillac Fleetwood      8
#>  7 Lincoln Continental     8
#>  8 Chrysler Imperial       8
#>  9 Fiat 128                4
#> 10 Honda Civic             4
#> 11 Toyota Corolla          4

labels <- tibble(lower = c(0,5), 
                 upper = c(5,10), 
                 label = c("B1", "B2"))

left_join(mtcars_, labels, by = join_by(between(cyl, lower, upper, bounds = "[)"))) 
#> # A tibble: 11 × 5
#>    car                   cyl lower upper label
#>    <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 Merc 280                6     5    10 B2   
#>  2 Merc 280C               6     5    10 B2   
#>  3 Merc 450SE              8     5    10 B2   
#>  4 Merc 450SL              8     5    10 B2   
#>  5 Merc 450SLC             8     5    10 B2   
#>  6 Cadillac Fleetwood      8     5    10 B2   
#>  7 Lincoln Continental     8     5    10 B2   
#>  8 Chrysler Imperial       8     5    10 B2   
#>  9 Fiat 128                4     0     5 B1   
#> 10 Honda Civic             4     0     5 B1   
#> 11 Toyota Corolla          4     0     5 B1
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is fine but @stefan's comment provides a more straightforward answer.

Comment: @BenBolker , I believe the key here is *"/../based on intervals of a numeric variable of **another dataset** /../"*

Comment: See my answer (I agree that the separate data set makes it trickier). I'm guessing our answers are more or less equally good.

Answer (score 1):

Using the example in @margusl's answer, I think this invocation of `cut()` will work:

```r
mtcars_ 
   |> mutate(label = cut(cyl, 
                         breaks = union(labels$lower, labels$upper), 
                         labels = labels$label))
```

`c(labels$lower[1], labels$upper)` would be an alternative way to construct the `breaks` vector ...

This assumes the intervals in the interval/label table are (1) ordered and (2) contiguous ...

Comment: Building cut breaks with `union()`  is really nice

Comment: If intervals are contiguous but not ordered, `sort(union(...))` should work (there is no guarantee in the docs that `union()` will maintain *existing* ordering, but I'd be shocked if it didn't ...